# UINavigationController Interactive Pop Gesture cancellation Not Working in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
    {
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    }

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
    {
        [self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer setEnabled:YES];
       self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
    }
}
```

//Am using this code but it not working in iOS 8.3 .Is there any problem in storyboard or it is not supported in iOS 8. Am irritating please give me a solution.

Comment: Can you add some more details? What should the code do? What actually happens? Are there any error messages? Dies it compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom `UIBarButtonItem`  and then set it in your navigation controller

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

it might be helpful for you.

Comment: Actually the problem was not in navigation bar. when am using show segue's like for example in login screen after login successfully, it goes to home screen in that home screen when i swipe from left to right then again it is going back to login screen.

Comment: Ok then you have to start your app from Home screen and present Login screen inside `viewDidAppear`  of home screen. I am using the same technique and its working very fine.

Comment: Yeah it is working.... self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;                                                                                                      Using this code in viewDidLoad of Home screen and login screen then it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 2 lines in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method where you want to disable pop gesture

```
[self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO];
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Already am tried this but again it goes to back when swipe left side of the screen .